# UrbanCode Deploy Export / Import of Components

Tags: ucd

Is it safe to create a new UrbanCode Deploy component by exporting the original component to a JSON file, changing the name, and importing it as a new component? Are there other fields (UUIDs, etc.) that need to be changed so that there won't be conflicts or overwrites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is much safer and quicker to just use the "Copy" action for the component if you can.  Is there some reason you can't?  If you have to import, it should be ok, but you likely want to make sure you leave all of the Import Component options as the defaults (e.g. leave the Upgrade component checkbox empty) to avoid damaging/changing other linked objects.

Comment: Why? Because I was looking in the main Component list, instead of the Component Template's list of Components! :-)   I was pretty sure I had seen a Copy button at one point, and it didn't make any sense to not have one. I just was looking in the wrong place.

Thanks for saving me from a huge hassle!

Comment: Sure.  Yes, sometimes the Actions in one UCD context are not visible in another where it would make sense as well.